# How do I know if my 3.5mm jack supports line-in?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I have a Lenovo X220 and I want to know if the 3.5mm audio jack supports line-in with an external mic, or if it is only line-out.

How do I find out this information? If it works, how do I switch to line-in?

I attached all the images I could get from `alsamixer`.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The person that made those sliders sure had imagination :+)

Comment: I did not find a command to check this. But came across this old topic ... if this still works http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/ it should tell you straight away if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I find out this information?

You google 'x220 line-in' and find lots and lots of pages, among them the [manual](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/x220_x220i_x220tablet_x220itablet_ug_en.pdf).
So it is both line-in and line-out, but with a limitation:

> The combo audio jack does not support a conventional microphone

Comment: tried and true!